# Popup is not opening inside switch statement

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to open a popup  when a button is clicked. The `post_request_value` is decided 1, 2 or 3 based upon the switch expression `choice`.

```
function OpenPopup() {
alert(choice); // this line works and hence removed from the code
            var choice = document.getElementById('dropdownlistid').value;
            switch(choice){
                case 1:
                    window.open("popup_page_name.aspx", "List", "scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=480", "post_request_value=1");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    window.open("popup_page_name.aspx", "List", "scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=480", "post_request_value=2");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    window.open("popup_page_name.aspx", "List", "scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=800,height=480", "post_request_value=3");
                    break;
            }
            return false;

    }
```

when window.open is placed outside the switch block it works. But when it is placed inside the switch case, the page simply finishes loading without showing popup.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: To ask the obvious, are you certain that `choice` has a value of 1, 2, or 3 when you run the code?

Comment: yes, alert shows the value

Comment: What is the type of the returned value. You should probably write `switch (parseInt(choice))`

Comment: The value of choice is most likely "1", "2", or "3" (strings), which are not equal to 1,2,3 (ints)

Comment: oops, thanks @AlexandruSeverin, I forgot this point. Let me check this and come back

Comment: thanks @AlexandruSeverin. Got it fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `choice` variable can be `"1", "2", "3"`, which are strings, and not integers. Try this code:

```
var choice = parseInt(document.getElementById('dropdownlistid').value);
```

And your code should work.

Comment: ...or switch on string literals `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"`.

Comment: Yes, that would also work, but it's easier to work with the code provided by the OP so they don't have to modify as much.

Comment: No problem whatsoever!